# Shifting multipart labels for an entire layer results into disappearing labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers, multipart, singlepart

When I attempt to move a multipart label, all of the labels asides the one I am moving disappear. How can I manually move a label and preserve all of the corresponding multipart labels using QGIS 3.60? Bear in mind i am doing this for an entire layer.

Comment: Can you provide an example for you labels? How are you moving them?

Comment: I think it come from the fact that when you move a label its position became hard coded. So for multipart label it just place the hardcoded label and consider the labeling done. unfortunately I don't have a solution for this other than creating a singlepart layer just for labeling purpose....

Comment: @J.R Exactly what i did, and it seems to have worked out fine. I converted the multipart into single part(Vector > Geometry>multipart to singleparts)  thereafter i created a new column(to give each polygon a disntinct id) in newly generated singleparts layer. when shifting the labels this time i selected  the new id column , works fine